# Unit testing activities marked as @ManualActivityCompletion

Tags: unit-testing, amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

I have been working on creating unit tests which run local versions of a workflow. I followed this [guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/test.html) for an initial setup. With that setup, I have been able to successfully execute and test a workflow. The issue arises when I attempt to unit test an activity implementation that is marked as @ManualActivityCompletion. It appears that the manual completion activities return normally within unit tests (not waiting for a completion/failure call).

I'm wondering if it is even possible to unit tests manual completion activities in this way. My guess is that it is not since I have seen no mention of it and I don't see any way to create a test ManualActivityCompletionClient. In that case, I'm wondering if anyone has any suggestions on how to unit test manual completion activities in a local workflow. I have attempted to create workarounds to this by using different threads and synch points, but it is useful to test with the actual behavior of completing/failing activities (exceptions that are thrown, etc.). It may be worth mentioning that I have been able to write successful integration unit tests for manual completion activities.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To test workflow logic that invokes activity marked with @ManualActivityCompletion just mock client side interface of this activity directly. As client executes in the asynchronous context of the workflow you can use Promises and WorkflowClock to implement your tests.